# Why can't I seem to target this asp:button?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm currently in the process of styling a website and have hit a bit of a rut.

I'm trying to target and style this:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Details" CssClass="update_btn" />
```

Using this CSS:

```
div#account .update_btn {
width:108px;
height:27px;
background:url("/furniture/images/buttons/update.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
clear:both;
float:left;
}
```

However when I inspect the button in firebug it doesn't appear.
It's currently being styled by the code below but the one above doesn't even appear.

```
div#account input {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width:150px;
padding:5px 0 5px 10px;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
float:right;
}
```

I don't know ASP so I can't make alterations and I can't use input.button[type="submit"] as it isn't supported by IE7.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the div with the `account` ID have a `runat="server"`? That would change the generated ID.

Comment: @TiesonT. but it's working in the other CSS

Comment: @Tieson T. It doesn't have `runat="server"` on the account div

Comment: @codingbiz Ah, that was not how I read that paragraph. Good catch.

Comment: @OkamiStudio Can you post a copy of the generated HTML for that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
div#account input.update_btn {
width:108px;
height:27px;
background:url("/furniture/images/buttons/update.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
clear:both;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Aha - more specificity! I'm still relatively new to CSS & HTML and am still learning how best to target things. Rookie error, thanks for being kind enough to point it out to me!

Answer (score 1):

Put a comma in your style it should work fine.

```
div#account, .update_btn {
```

Comment: The OP is trying to style a classed item that's a child of `account`; this selector would have unintended consequences